# Google maps infobubble link click delegate() or live() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am using this custom window for balloon tips
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/

this is the code I have so far

```
var map;
            var ibs = [];   
            function loadMap() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.2175, 2.0614);    // center of europe
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: false
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

                var typeToIcons = {
                    "STORE": "garnish/store-pin.png",
                    "HOTEL": "garnish/hotel-pin.png"
                }


                placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(38.101063330, 23.810806274), "<span class=\"logo\"\></span\> <h3\>Kifissia</h3\> <div class=\"details\"\> <p\><strong\>Address: </strong\>Foo 13, Athens, Bar, Ελλάδα (Αττική) Foo 13, Athens, Bar, Ελλάδα (Αττική) Foo 13, Athens, Bar, Ελλάδα (Αττική) Foo 13, Athens, Bar, Ελλάδα (Αττική)</p\> <p\><strong\>Telephone: </strong\>23654632543</p\> <p\><strong\>Fax: </strong\>27634734672</p\> <p\><strong\>Email: </strong\> <a href=\'mailto:gasds@ss.cc\' title=\'gasds@ss.cc\'\>gasds@ss.cc</a\> </p\> </div\> <a href=\"http://localhost:8080/cocomat/location-item?id=1\" class=\"pop requiresJs\" title=\"Read more\"\>Read more</a\>", typeToIcons.STORE);

                placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(38.620449844, 21.410079002), "<span class=\"logo\"\></span\> <h3\>Αgrinio</h3\> <div class=\"details\"\> <p\><strong\>Address: </strong\>Lam 56, Bla, TYY, Ελλάδα (Ηπειρωτική)</p\> <p\><strong\>Telephone: </strong\>783487328</p\> <p\><strong\>Fax: </strong\>7423893278</p\> <p\><strong\>Email: </strong\> <a href=\'mailto:jhjhdf@fuf.cc\' title=\'jhjhdf@fuf.cc\'\>jhjhdf@fuf.cc</a\> </p\> </div\> <a href=\"http://localhost:8080/cocomat/location-item?id=2\" class=\"pop requiresJs\" title=\"Read more\"\>Read more</a\>", typeToIcons.STORE);

                geocode("International");

            }

            function placeMarker(position, content, markerIcon) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: position,
                    icon: markerIcon
                });



                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {



                    for(var i in ibs) {
                        ibs[i].close();
                    }

                    var ib = new InfoBubble({
                    content:content,
                    backgroundColor:"#F4F4F4",
                    borderRadius:0,
                    backgroundClassName:"infoBox bubble",
                    disableAnimation:true,
                    minHeight:250,
                    maxWidth:232,
                    arrowSize:15,
                    arrowPosition:25});



                ibs.push(ib);

                    if (!ib.isOpen()) {

                        ib.open(map, marker);
                    }

                });
            }

            // fit map bounds to selected country
            function geocode(country) {
                new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({'address': country}, function(results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        // first result is the most specific
                        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
                    }
                });
            }

            $(function(){
                loadMap();

                $('body').delegate('.pop','click',function(){
                    window.open($(this).attr('href'), "locationItem", "scrollbars=1, toolbar=0, status=0, menubar=0, width=800, height=500");
                    return false;
                });



            });
```

The problem is that the delegate() function doesn't work. I've also tried the live()

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and [here's a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370063/1331671) that works:

```
$(infoBubble.bubble_).live("click", function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just attach DOM events using google apis dom events

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("infobubble_id", 'click', myFunctionThatOpensAWindow);
```

More info:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#DomEvents

Comment: I have many infobubbles and each one of them has a link with .pop class. I need to listen to the event dispatched from the link

Comment: I've modified the infobubble to add the popup link dynamically and used the addDomListener and it works. I'll post the answer later

Comment: Good suggestion. I think it's most important to ascertain why it is not working via jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least kind of solve this problem by modifying the library...I'm not sure if there's a better way to make delegate and live work, but this seems to work correctly.

If you look for this piece of code in the InfoBubble library, you can see where it handles bubbling of events:

```
/**
 * Add events to stop propagation
 * @private
 */
InfoBubble.prototype.addEvents_ = function() {
  // We want to cancel all the events so they do not go to the map
  var events = ['mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mouseup',
      'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'touchstart', 'touchend', 'touchmove',
      'dblclick', 'contextmenu', 'click'];

  var bubble = this.bubble_;
  this.listeners_ = [];
  for (var i = 0, event; event = events[i]; i++) {
    this.listeners_.push(
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(bubble, event, function(e) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      })
    );
  }
};
```

If you remove 'click' from the events array, the click delegation works as expected.  Like I said though, there's probably a better way than that.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to bind an event to an anchor that I add to the bubble content. The problem I was having was in the function I couldn't search the DOM for the element. I had to search the infobubble.

The way I have this set up - 
I click a marker and it calls a function that updates the contents of the info bubble. After the contents are updated the infoBubble opens. The contents of the info bubble are located in "infoBubble.j". I check for the close button's class (or ID) inside of infoBubble.j, and once I've found it I add the click function.

See below for how I set it as the context and added the click function.

```
$('.bubble-wrap-close', infoBubble.j).click(function(){
    infoBubble.close();
});
```

Obviously, "bubble-wrap-close" is the class I gave to my close button, not a native class for the close button in infoBubble.

I don't think you have to open the infoBubble to find the anchor or other elements in it's contents. Just search for your class in the context of infoBubble.j and bind your function to it as I did above.

Hopefully you'll be able to use this method to attach your delegate function.

Good Luck

Comment: it might be something like
`$(infoBubble.j).delegate('.pop','click',function(){
                    window.open($(this).attr('href'), "locationItem", "scrollbars=1, toolbar=0, status=0, menubar=0, width=800, height=500");
                    return false;
                });`