# Google Maps API - Event Listener for InfoBubble doesn't work

Tags: events, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I need an event listener waiting for a click. Unfortunately the way it worked with `InfoWindows` doesn't seem to work here...

Well, here's my `InfoBubble`:

```
var infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      map: map,
      content: $('#my-div').html(),
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(areas[area].lat, areas[area].lng),
      shadowStyle: 1,
      padding: 0,
      borderRadius: 0,
      arrowSize: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#ccc',
      disableAutoPan: true,
      hideCloseButton: true,
      arrowPosition: 15,
      arrowStyle: 0
    });
```

And here's my listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoBubble, 'click', function(){

        console.log("noodle");  
    });
```

BTW, there are no errors reported by Firebug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(infoBubble.bubble_).live("click", function() {
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the compiled version of InfoBubble, the .bubble_ reference is lost. You have to find what .bubble_ has been changed into. 
If you haven't compiled your own and you've use the supplied compiled version, the .bubble_ reference is **.e**.
Example:

```
$(infoBubble.e).find("#yourdiv").live("click",function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Comment: `$(infoBubble.e).on("click",function(e) { })` works in versions of jQuery where live has been depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(infoBubble.bubble_, 'click', function() {
    alert("Ooo..!");
});
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

To further improve on @Marius' answer, as well as update it for the current versions of jQuery (given that I can see that the OP has jQuery available), try the following to target the click event on a specific element within your infoBubble:

```
$(infoBubble.bubble_).on("click", "button.close", function() {
    console.log("Button with class .close clicked.");
});
```

If you need to pass data to your function, one option is to use data-* attributes and grab it through the event *target*, as follows:

Example JS for your InfoBubble content:

```
var myVariable = 10;
var infoBubbleContentString = '<span class="my-style" data-id="' + myVariable + '">Button text</span>';
```

Event handler:

```
$(infoBubble.bubble_).on("click", ".my-style", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).data('id')) {
        var myVariableValue = $(e.target).data('id'); // myVariableValue will equal 10
    }
});
```